# Conservation of Momentum - Rocket

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, conservation-laws, rocket-science

[image: Question]

[image: Answer]

I was wondering why the mass of the fuel is regarded as **-dm** and the mass of the rocket as **m+dm**? I understand that the total mass has to be unchanged (ie **m**). Why can't I say that the rocket's mass is **m-dm** and the mass of the fuel being ejected is **dm**? When I do that and continue with the suggested answer, I get v but in the opposite direction. Would appreciate any explanation

Comment: Look at the "classical" (or "ideal") rocket equation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation

Answer (score 2):

Here, $\mathscr{d}m$ is inherently **negative** because rockets mass decreases with time.

$$
\mathscr{d}m = -|dm|
$$

And the rocket's mass is,

$$
m + \mathscr{d}m = m - |\mathscr{d}m|
$$

For reference, please look Young's University Physics with Modern Physics, Ch 8, Sec 8.6